# DC Bias network for a LCR meter

Tags: protection, zener, bias, lcr

I am trying to make a DC bias network for my LCR meter (Scientific SM6023) based on this circuit I found online [image: DC biasing circuit]

RD10E has a Zener voltage of about 10V and 1N4004 has a forward voltage of 1V. I have some questions regarding this circuit and the diodes used to protect the LCR meter from over voltages:

1. Is it okay to let the biasing capacitors charge through the Hcur and Hpot terminals of the LCR meter? I am asking because the connections to ground through the diodes would only occur at voltages greater than 10V
2. Why do I need different protection arrangements for the Hpot and Hcur terminals? As far as I understand the two Zeners in series will conduct when voltage at Hcur exceeds 10V and the Zener + normal combination will do so when it exceeds 11V in either polarity, apart from which I see no difference.